# Modifying nested json conditionally using jq

Tags: json, nested, updates, jq

I would like to modify something like the following JSON:

```
{
  "foobar": {
    "a": {
      "adkjfe": {
        "A": 1,
        "foo": "bar"
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "ekjaei": {
        "A": 2,
        "bar": "foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to add more data say `{"baz": ["bing", "bop"]}` to the parent of A if A=1. Assuming I don't know the parent key while leaving the rest of the json untouched. I've tried many different things including:

```
.foobar | .. | .. | .[] | if select(.A==1) then . += {"baz": "bing"} else . end
```

which gives me an error and only my modified section.

The result, in this case, that I would like to see is:

```
{
  "foobar": {
    "a": {
      "adkjfe": {
        "A": 1,
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": ["bing", "bop"]
      }
    },
    "b": {
      "ekjaei": {
        "A": 2,
        "bar": "foo"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select only fields that are of type `object` and that match your condition (`A == 1`) :

```
jq '(.foobar | .. | select(type == "object" and .A == 1)) |= .+ {"baz": ["bing", "bop"]}' test.json
```

The `()` around the filter query take care that the whole document will be returned with the updated fields and not just your subdocument

Comment: Works like buttah! Thank you!

Comment: it seems also possible to use `| objects` in place of `type == "object"` since jq 1.4 which may be more readable.

Answer (score 4):

In general it is better to avoid `..` if possible, for reasons of efficiency. In the present case, the following will do the job:

```
(.foobar[][] | select(.A == 1)) |= .+ {"baz":["bing", "bop"]}
```

Comment: This works because each `[]` essentially moves down one object tree level, so this solution searches at a fixed 2-levels deep.  (This has been a conceptual problem for me since my mind is conditioned to think 'array' when it sees `[]`).  And it's more efficient because the `..` literally iterates every node right out to the leaf, which may be unnecessary, though probably unavoidable if the structure is more ragged.